# Unable to test expressjs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js

I want to run some basic test on my expressjs server and immediately close it, but somehow I can't figure out how.
I'm exporting the server as a promise.

Here is my server file : index.js

```
const config = require("./config");
const express = require("express");
// Other imports
const app = express();


const ServerInfo = DatabaseService.init().then(
  () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   
      // Load middlewares.

      // Load routes /api.

      let server = app.listen(config.port, config.host, () => {
       logger.log(
          "info",
          `Server started on : http://${config.host}:${config.port}`
        );
        resolve(server);
      });

 
      });
    }),
  (err) => {
    console.log("error", "Database is not ready!");
  }
);

module.exports = ServerInfo;
```

Here is my test file:

```
const chai = require("chai");
const config = require("../../config");
const server = require("../../index");

const expect = chai.expect;

describe("Server", () => {
  it("tests server starts on configured port.", function () {
    return server.then((serverObj) => {
      console.log(serverObj.address.port());
      expect(serverObj.address().port).to.equal(config.port);
    });
  });
});
```

I intend to exit the program once the test is done.

**Update**

Finally I got it to work by updating the test file like so.

```
const chai = require("chai");
const config = require("../../config");
const server = require("../../index");

const expect = chai.expect;
describe("Server", () => {
  it("tests server starts on configured port & host", function (done) {
    this.timeout(15000);
    server
      .then((serverObj) => {
        expect(serverObj.address().address).to.equal(config.host);
        expect(serverObj.address().port).to.equal(config.port);
        return serverObj;
      })
      .then((serverObj) => {
        serverObj.close(() => {
          done();
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        done(err);
      });
  });
});
```

Now the problem is that the test hangs without exiting after running all the test, I guess because the server doesn't close. Calling server.close() doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably how you are importing the packages.

If you could use [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), the proper way to call `expect` from `chai` would be.

```js
import { expect } from "chai";
```

However, you're using `require`. Try using this.

```js
const expect = require("chai").expect;
```

or

```js
const chai = require("chai");
const expect = chai.expect;
```

The last way might be the most helpful if you need more than one method or property from Chai.

Also, check to make sure that your `package.json` file is set to run `mocha` when you run `node test`.

Comment: Thank u @JRCharney . let me try this.